# How can I fix the "pid must be a number" error in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, error-handling

My code is not running and giving me an error called "pid must be a number" while I try to run it in VS Code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywNZ1.png)

Answer (score 0):

[Updated]

If you using "Code runner" VScode extension:

1. Open VScode.
2. On the left bottom-corner click on Manage and go into the settings.
3. In the search settings type code runner, scroll-down and delete the path prefilled in 'Set the working directory'.

[if step 3 doesn't do it, try]

3. In the search settings type code runner, scroll-down and put a tick-mark in 'Run In Terminal'.

Answer (score 0):

VS Code Terminal: Manage (gear icon bottom-left) -->Settings--> Code-runner: Run in Terminal--> X Whether to run code in Integrated Terminal. This will stop the [running] cd .... in the OUTPUT and the ERR message:> pid must be a number < will disappear.